# Renaming Files in Multiple Iterations

Tags: powershell, refactoring

I have a folder with a varying amount of files, all of the same form, which I download in batches from a share site.

The downloaded files are all auto-named with a similar pattern, however, it is not the end pattern that I require for my server. The code below gets the job done, but it seems clunky and my gut says there is a better way to write multiple replacements on a filename. Please help me re-code this.

I've tried multiple pipelines and it seems the issue lies in the fact that once the files are renamed with the first iteration, all my references after that do not hold. Hence after replacement, I need to create a new variable for that new iteration.

```
$pathToRFIs = 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\*.pdf'
$path2ToRFIs = 'C:\Users\user\Downloads'

$text = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo


$lowerRFIs = gci -path $pathToRFIs -filter *rfi*
$lowerRFIs | ren -newname {"$($text.ToTitleCase($_.BaseName))$($_.Extension)"}

$properRFIs = gci -path $pathToRFIs -filter *rfi*
$properRFIs | ren -newname {$_.name -replace '___',' & '}

$andRFIs = gci -path $pathToRFIs -filter *rfi*
$andRFIs | ren -newname {$_.name -replace '_',' '}

$spaceRFIs = gci -path $pathToRFIs -filter *rfi*
$spaceRFIs | ren -newname {$_.name -replace 'Encinitas Beach Resort-Rfi ','RFI 00'}

$RFIs = gci -path $pathToRFIs  -filter *RFI*
$RFIs | ren -newname {$_.name -replace '^(.*?)-', '$1_'}

$RFIs_ = gci -path $pathToRFIs -filter *RFI*
$RFIs_ | ren -newname {$_.name.substring(0,$_.name.length-17)}

$finalRFIs = gci -path $path2ToRFIs *"RFI 0"*
$finalRFIs | ren -newname {$_.fullname + ".pdf"}
```

For reference, the file I receive would be like this:

```
"encinitas beach resort-rfi 31-public water closets-201903221442.pdf"
```

The desired end-result name would be:

```
"RFI 0031_Public Water Closets.pdf"
```

Comment: instead of piping directly to the Rename-Item cmdlet, you can pipe to the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet and then do all but the last replace as a chained series of `-replace` operations. that will save you a bit of time & CPU cycles since sending stuff across the pipeline takes resources. [*grin*] then, finally, do that last `-replace` and use the result in a single `Rename_Item` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There are no intermediate variables necessary
- nor a ForEach-Object
- all transformatins can be stuck to each other, here on seperate lines with a backtick
- and a trailing `-Whatif` to only show what happened if..

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\03\29\SO_55424102.ps1
$pathToRFIs = 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\*.pdf'

$text = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo

Get-ChildItem -Path $pathToRFIs -Filter *rfi* |
    Rename-Item -NewName {($text.ToTitleCase($_.BaseName) `
       -replace '___',' & ' `
       -replace '_',' ' `
       -replace 'Encinitas Beach Resort-Rfi ','RFI 00' `
       -replace '(?<=^[^-]*)-', '_' `
       -replace '-\d{12}$')+$_.Extension} -WhatIf
```

Sample output (German locale):

```
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei umbenennen" für das 
Ziel "Element: Q:\Test\2019\03\29\encinitas beach resort-rfi 31-public water closets-201903221442.pdf 
         Ziel: Q:\Test\2019\03\29\RFI 0031_Public Water Closets.pdf".
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf`

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for, I just didn't know what the proper syntax would've been.

Comment: If answers solve your question or you find them helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 0):

By using `ForEach-Object` as [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) suggested, you can use a regex `-match` to capture the parts of the filename you want. (number and subject).

Then, inside the loop do the renaming stuff like this:

```
$pathToRFIs = 'C:\Users\user\Downloads'

Get-ChildItem -Path $pathToRFIs -Filter '*rfi*' -File | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.BaseName -match '.*rfi\s+(?<number>\d+)-(?<subject>.*)\s*-\d+$') {
        $subject = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($matches['subject']) -replace '___',' & ' -replace '_', ' '
        $newName = 'RFI {0:D4}_{1}{2}' -f ([int]$matches['number']), $subject, $_.Extension

        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Take off the `-WhatIf` switch if you're happy with the results.

Using this, a file like `encinitas beach resort-rfi 31-public water closets-201903221442.pdf` will become
`RFI 0031_Public Water Closets.pdf`.

Regex details:

> ```
> .              # Match any single character that is not a line break character
>    *           # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> rfi            # Match the characters “rfi” literally
> \s             # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
>    +           # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> (?<number>     # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “number”
>    \d          # Match a single digit 0..9
>       +        # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> )
> -              # Match the character “-” literally
> (?<subject>    # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “subject”
>    .           # Match any single character that is not a line break character
>       *        # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> )
> \s             # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
>    *           # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> -              # Match the character “-” literally
> \d             # Match a single digit 0..9
>    +           # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> $              # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
> ```

Comment: Did you write out that regex explanation or is there a tool for that?  That was really fast if it was all you

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I always use RegexBuddy. Great for trying out regexes and afterwards you can get these details aswell. (just need to do a bit of formatting on it). Not free though..

Comment: Some of the transformations (not occuring in the sample) are missing. `'___'`=>`' & '` , `'_'`=>`' '`.

Comment: @LotPings Well spotted. Easy fix though ;)

Comment: @Theo Thanks for the regex intro! I just tried your code however and after hitting run in the PowerShell ISE, the terminal just shows the code and doesn't seem to actually do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: @codegreens Yep. Take off the `-WhatIf` switch to actually rename the files. That switch is there for testing. P.s. If the code is not saved yet, the ISE shows the code when run. After you save it as a .ps1 file it stops doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer: yes.  Note this is just a transform of the work you've already done.  By using a single call to `Rename-Item` and using `foreach` over `ForEach-Object`, it will also be significantly faster.

```
$text = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\*.pdf -Filter *rfi*) {
    $rename = $text.ToTitleCase($file.BaseName) + $file.Extension
    $rename = $rename -replace '_{3}', ' & ' -replace '_', ' ' -replace 'Encinitas Beach Resort-Rfi ', 'RFI 00'
    $rename = $rename -replace '^(.*?)-', '$1_'
    $rename = $rename.Substring(0, $rename.Length - 17) + '.pdf'
    $file | Rename-Item -NewName $rename
}
```

*one regex to rule them all minus the casing:*

```
$n -replace '.*?-rfi (\d+)-(.*?)-.*', 'RFI $1_$2.pdf'
```